# Need to understand how to display this XML feed into HTML. Simply looking to pull in Soccer Team Names and the Score

Tags: javascript, html, json, xml, rss

Looking to understand how to display this XML feed into HTML. Simply looking to pull in Soccer Team Names and the Score. Please help!!! If possible, I would love to display basic HTML that pulls in just the team names and scores that are associated with the XML snippet below. Please keep in mind that the file locally was stored as "soccer.xml".

XML Snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Soccer>
    <Details VisitingTeam="Argentina" VisitorScore="2" HomeTeam="USA" HomeScore="4" />
</Soccer>
```

```js
//Display it
function displayFEED(i) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this, i);
    }
  };
  //Call XML Feed with Live URL
  xmlhttp.open("GET", 'soccer.xml', true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
displayFEED(1);

// Call tag names from XML and match ID's
function myFunction(xml, i) {
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Soccer");
  document.getElementById("HomeTeam").innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Details")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById("HomeScore").innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Details")[1].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById("VisitingTeam").innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Details")[2].childNodes[2].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById("VisitorScore").innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Details")[3].childNodes[3].nodeValue;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Testing Soccer XML Score Feed</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="display-8">Testing Soccer XML Score Feed</h1>
      <hr class="my-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div id="HomeTeam"></div>
          <div id="HomeScore"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div id="VisitingTeam"></div>
          <div id="VisitorScore"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where do you load the HTML document from, the local file system or a local web server (e.g. `http://localhost/dir/page.html`)?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Just local host

Comment: If the XMLHttpRequest problem is solved and you need help with the rest of the code, consider to use an executable code sample that allows us to run and see any errors you are struggling with. It is currently not possible to run your code, due to the XMLHttpRequest dependency. Also having an XML document sample with a single `Details` element while showing code doing `getElementsByTagName("Details")[3]` doesn't allow us to understand what you want to achieve and where you fail. Perhaps show more details of the input and the output you want to create.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Gotcha! Thank you. 

Out of the current code above, maybe we simplify a bit. Any idea how I can out of the above XML just display the Team Names and Scores? I could be doing this completly wrong. That's my goal is to just pull that in.